# How to find forget password in QGIS DB manager?

Tags: qgis, password

I am new to QGIS. I forget the DB manager password

[image].

Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

Change in your pg_hba.conf file the line for localhost:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             postgres                                trust
host    all             postgres        127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             postgres        ::1/128                 trust
```

Restart your postgres instance.
It allows you to connect to the database as postgres user from localhost with no password. Start psql and change the password for postgres user and reset your pg_hba.con file.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can I also ask where to find the pg_hba.conf file on Mac?

Comment: You may need root/superuser rights to edit the file (or to change the access rights) on some OS.

Comment: There is a topic about mac and pg_hba.conf file on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025972/postgresql-how-to-find-pg-hba-conf-file-using-mac-os-x